# How to recreate a (0-1)matrix given the number of 1s in each row and column?

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array

The first part to this program was randomly generating a matrix with dimensions between 2 and 6. Then I had to fill this matrix up with 1s and 0s randomly. Using this matrix, I made 2 one-dimensional arrays containing the number of 1's in each row and column. The index of the matrix representing the row number, and the number in the cell representing the count. I made 2 of these arrays: one for row count and one for column count.
Here was my code for that.

```
    public static void count(int[][] matrix, int[] rowcount, int[] colcount)
  {
     for(int x = 0; x < rowcount.length; x++)
        for(int y = 0; y < colcount.length; y++)
        {
           if (matrix[x][y] == 1)
           {
              rowcount[x] = rowcount[x] + 1;
              colcount[y] = colcount[y] + 1;
           }
        }
  }
```

Now the problem I'm facing is to recreate this matrix using these counts. **By recreate, I mean just create another matrix that satisfies the the counts of the 1-D arrays, it is not necessary to generate the exact matrix that these counts were derived from.**
Here is my code for that so far, I've been working on this for program for 2 days and I can't find an algorithm to generate a matrix for all cases.

Here are the methods for that

```
    public static void re_create(int[] rowcount, int[] colcount)
  {
     int[][] recreated = new int[rowcount.length][colcount.length];
     recur(recreated, rowcount, colcount, 0, 0);
  }
  private static void recur(int[][] m, int[] rowcount, int[] colcount, int r, int c) //recursive helper method
  {
     if(compare(m, rowcount, colcount))    //base case: if new matrix works
     {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("RECREATED");
        display(m, rowcount, colcount);    //we're done!
        System.exit(0);
     }
     else
     { 
        int[] temp_r = new int[m.length];
        int[] temp_c = new int[m[0].length];
        count(m, temp_r, temp_c);
        if(rowcount[r] > temp_r[r] && colcount[c] > temp_c[c])
           m[r][c] = 1;
        if(r+1 < m.length)
           recur(m,rowcount,colcount,r+1,c);
        if(rowcount[r] < temp_r[r] || colcount[c] < temp_c[c])
           m[r][c] = 0;
        if(c+1 < m[0].length)
           recur(m,rowcount,colcount,r,c+1);     
     }
  }
  private static boolean compare(int[][] m, int[] rowcount, int[] colcount)
  {
     int[] temp_r = new int[m.length];
     int[] temp_c = new int[m[0].length];
     count(m, temp_r, temp_c);

     for (int x = 0; x < temp_r.length; x++)
     {
        if(temp_r[x] != rowcount[x])
           return false;
     }

     for (int y = 0; y < temp_c.length; y++)
     {
        if(temp_c[y] != colcount[y])
           return false;
     }

     return true; 
  }
```

The program is from school, so I was already given the method header and the base case for the recursive method, so those must stay the same. Everything else was written by me. I just can't find a good algorithm to generate these matrices. I think I'm supposed to generate every permutation of 1s and 0s in the matrix until one  matches the base case, but I don't understand how that would work given the arguments in the recur method.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution that will work for all cases. Consider:

```
0 1 0 0 | 1    0 0 1 0 | 1
1 0 1 0 | 2    0 1 0 1 | 2
0 1 0 1 | 2    1 0 1 0 | 2
0 0 1 0 | 1    0 1 0 0 | 1
-------        -------
1 2 2 1        1 2 2 1
```

Comment: Well, actually both those solutions work, so either one of those are accepted by the program. As I said above, the programs job is to recreate any matrix given the counts. What I mean by solutions is that sometimes the program ends without finding the base case. It just prints the original matrix and neither one of the solutions. The program ends without reaching the base case

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with. Seems correct to me, but I didn't feed it a lot of test data.

```
public static void re_create(int[] rowcount, int[] colcount) {
    int[][] recreated = new int[rowcount.length][colcount.length];
    for (int y = 0; y < rowcount.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < colcount.length; x++) {
            if (rowcount[y] > 0 && colcount[x] > 0) {
                recreated[x][y] = 1;
                rowcount[y]--;
                colcount[x]--;
            } else {
                recreated[x][y] = 0;
            }
        }
        if (rowcount[y] != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossible! y = " + y);
        }
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < colcount.length; x++) {
        if (colcount[x] != 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Impossible! x = " + x);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(recreated));
}
```

Comment: this is good^, but I need to use the recur method to solve this.

Comment: the recreate method is just used to create an empty matrix, call the recur method and pass down the counts.

Comment: Ok, I missed that the first lines of the recur method were given and had to be used. I'll give it another try.

Comment: My solution is also wrong, e.g. with {1, 2, 3, 4} for both rowcount and colcount. I will delete it after you read this (I have not enough reputation to add comments directly to your question).
I don't have time to look further into this at the moment, maybe I'll return to it later if it's still open.

Comment: Regarding the use of recursion: normally, you call a function recursively with a simpler/smaller input. E.g. here, if a row has a count of 0, you can put all zeroes in that row and call the same method with a matrix with one row less. Same for columns. Same for a maximum rowcount, you can put all ones in that row, subtract 1 from each colcount, and again call the same method with a matrix with one row less. But this still doesn't cover all cases, you'll have to look further into this.